# What's the name of the style of 3-8 lowercase letters in programming?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you go on GitHub, so many of the project names are 3-8 lowercase letters. So many directories of those projects are 3-8 lowercase letters.

In the base level directory of most unix OS's, the directories are 3-8 lowercase letters.

This occurs even if the directory's name is an abbreviation for something a bit longer, and occurs *even at the expense of clarity*. For example, for the longest time I had no clue what sbin, proc, var were.

I'm led to believe that this is a stylistic choice among programmers, because it looks cool or something (not making fun of it; it does look cool and adds a level of consistency to directory names).

Does anyone know of a name of this style?

Comment: Hello, extremea. isn't this virtually confined to programming jargon? As such, it's not really standard English usage, and is better asked on say Computer Science SE.

Comment: Unix users tend to use the command line, typing short names is preferred to long names. "usr" instead of user, "src" instead of source, "bin" instead of binary, "sbin" instead of static binary, "lib" instead of library. And so on.